# Grouping times values by hour

Tags: php, mysql

Result of my query looks like that:

```
05:02:00    
05:22:00    
05:48:00    
06:17:00    
06:41:00    
07:10:00    
07:27:00    
07:46:00
```

And what I would like to achieve is to have it like this:

```
5 - 02, 22, 48

6 - 17, 41

7 - 10, 27, 46
```

How can I do it in PHP?

Comment: Show us what you have so far

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select date/time groupings in MySQL grouped by hour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258725/select-date-time-groupings-in-mysql-grouped-by-hour)

Comment: Please show us your code (and what you've tried so far).

Comment: What does JSON have to do with a SQL query?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT HOUR(datetime) h, GROUP_CONCAT(MINUTE(datetime)) m
FROM table
GROUP BY h
```

Answer (score 1):

Code([Demo on Codepad](http://codepad.org/wj9LTpw7)):

```
<?php
$result = array('05:02:00', // Your data array.
'05:22:00', 
'05:48:00',    
'06:17:00',    
'06:41:00',    
'07:10:00',    
'07:27:00',   
'07:46:00');

$end = array(); // Create array to hold grouped values.
foreach($result as $r) { // Loop over data array.
    $part = explode(':', $r); // Create array from strings.
    $end[$part[0]][] = $part[1]; // Store values inside $end array
}
echo '<pre>' . print_r($end, TRUE) . '</pre>'; // Echo array as preformatted text.
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [05] => Array
        (
            [0] => 02
            [1] => 22
            [2] => 48
        )

    [06] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17
            [1] => 41
        )

    [07] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 27
            [2] => 46
        )

)
```

To get output that you've asked for:

```
5 - 02, 22, 48
6 - 17, 41
7 - 10, 27, 46
```

Instead of `echo print_r()` use:

```
foreach($end as $hour => $minutes) {
    echo ltrim($hour, '0') . ' -';
    foreach($minutes as $index => $minute) {
        $comma = (($index + 1) == count($minutes)) ? '' : ',';
        echo ' ' . $minute . $comma;
    }
    echo '<br/>';
}
```